# adding layout on top os camera view

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using an android project as a plugin in unity.
The plugin Activity extends the QCARPlayerActivity.
i want a button should be displayed on top it.
I followed the link[Link](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/extending-unity-android-activity-and-adding-custom-views-eclipse)to add custom view.it's works fine,But when we use unity project as plugin in eclipse,the application crashes as soon as i starts.

Comment: Please post your Logcat Error.

Comment: hi i cant check the logcat error. because i am testing the project on device from unity. i am using java project as a plugin in unity. it works fine if i dont add any view but on adding view it crashes.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse any tag, and read carefully before using any tag.